# Why is this code not showing any oval

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add a oval to the frame and the frame shows up after executing the program with nothing displaying in it. The background color is even coming. Only the oval is not visible. Suggestions please.

```
   import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Example1 extends JFrame{


    Example1()
    {
        JFrame jp=new JFrame("spot");

         jp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jp.setVisible(true);
        jp.setSize(400,400);

    }

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
      super.paint(g);
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

      g.fillOval(100,50,40,50);

  }

  public static void main(String...args)
{

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Example1 obj = new Example1();


}
}
```

Comment: try to set the color first `g.setColor(Color.RED);` then fill the oval `g.fillOval(100,50,40,50);`, and there is no need for draw the oval, filling does it so.

Comment: first of all look the title of your question,correct the spelling mistakes

Comment: by the way, don't you forgot to add the component to the frame(`jp`)? maybe `jp.add(this)` in the constructor!?

Comment: @user2511414...i am not using any component..!! please see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are drawing oval in extended JComponent, which you not using anywhere.

You are just using JFrame, setting its background color and displaying it. You should have added extended JComponent in content pane of JFrame.

**EDIT**

You are extending JFrame to override paint() method, okay fine (**But this is not proper way**). But you are not using it to display GUI. You are creating some different JFrame in constructor of Example1 and displaying GUI with it.

You should display your extended JFrame. Like this:

```
    Example1 obj = new Example1();
    // Example1 extends JFrame, and overrides paint() method to display oval.
    // so display this Example1 frame, not creating some different JFrame.
    obj.setSize(400,400);
    obj.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: i am just extending the JFrame now. But still no positive results.

Comment: @user2935743, `Or you should draw oval in overridden protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){} method of JFrame` - there is no paintComponent() method in JFrame and you should NOT override paint() in JFrame either. `You should have added extended JComponent in content pane of JFrame.` - this is the proper way to do this. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

You draw first, then you set the color to red. Did you think that would change the color of the oval you drew previously?

Steps to painting:

1. Set the color
2. Draw

Comment: Yeah, because you're creating and displayin a new JFrame instead of your Example1 class. Make Example1 extend JPanel and put jp.setContentPane(this) in the constructor. And then go through the Swing tutorials so you'll learn to write Swing properly.

Comment: instead of extending the JPanel, i can simply use the getContentPane() if i want to add anything to a frame. Why extending a JPanel un-necessarily??

Comment: If you extend JPanel, you can just set your class as the content pane. Now you're creating 2 JFrames and doing all sorts of unnecessary crap. Why didn't you read the tutorial first?

Comment: thanx for all the scolding man..!! but just reading was not helping me either. But thanx, will go through it again.